# Yourls Errors in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, nginx, yourls

I have wordpress working well in mysite.com
but [YOURLS](http://yourls.org/) which is installed in mysite.com/u is not working, when I click on any shortened link I get a 404 error (wordpress).

However, I get [YOURLS](http://yourls.org/) to work by adding this to  nginx.conf

`location /u { try_files $uri $uri/ /u/yourls-loader.php;`

But then WordPress links break.

Here is my default [nginx.conf](http://p.ngx.cc/14) 
I know the fix is to add this  `try_files $uri $uri/ /u/yourls-loader.php;` somewhere in nginx.conf , but where to put it without breaking wordpress.?

===================  Update 1 =========================

I got this partially working. with same config, but I noticed that wordpress links that start with `u` doesn't work ex: `http://example.com/understand-math` instead it redirect to `Error 403 - Forbidden`

???

================ update 2 ============

ok I fixed it by just adding another slash `/` to `location /u/` instead of `location /u`

Comment: Did you try this settings `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php`?

Comment: @Rafael , the problem is within nginx config. wordpress is working well with no problem. the only problem is where to put this `location /yourls { try_files $uri $uri/ /yourls/yourls-loader.php;`  without breaking wordpress , I have included my nginx configuration for anyone willing to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**YOURLs NGINX CONFIGURATION**

```
server {

  # Listen IPv4 & v6
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  # Optional SSL stuff
  listen              443              ssl;
  listen              [::]:443         ssl;
  ssl_certificate     example.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key example.com.key;

  # Server names
  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  # Root directory (NEEDS CONFIGURATION)
  root /path/to/files;

  # Rewrites
  location / {

    # Try files, then folders, then yourls-loader.php
    # --- The most important line ---
    try_files $uri $uri/ /yourls-loader.php;

    # PHP engine
    location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files      $uri =404;
      fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; # Can be different
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include        fastcgi_params;
    }
  }
}
```

[GITHUB DOCUMENTATION](https://github.com/YOURLS/YOURLS/wiki/Nginx-configuration)

Comment: that's for /yourls installed in the root, but I have yourls installed in sub-directory, and wordpress installed in the root, I don't know how to make both of them working simultaneously.when I fix yourls I break wordpress and viceversa.

Comment: I edited the config file and chose it as the accepted answer, thank you :)